# Swift Protocols not working

Tags: ios, swift, protocols

I am trying to call a function using delegates and for some reason it is not working. I set `loginPresenter` as self in the `LoginPresenter` `init()` but it still didn't work. I am not sure what else to try? Am i missing how delegates work?

**Login View**

```
class LoginView: UIViewController {

    var loginPresenter: LoginPresenterProtocol?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


    }

    @objc func loginHandler() {
        print("Tapped")
        loginPresenter?.loginUser(username: "username", password: "123456")
    }
}
```

**Login Presenter View**

```
class LoginPresenter: LoginPresenterProtocol {
    weak var view: LoginViewProtocol?

    init() {
       view?.loginPresenter = self
    }

    func loginUser(username: String, password: String) {
        print("recieved")
    }
}
```

**Protocols**

```
protocol LoginViewProtocol: class {
    var loginPresenter: LoginPresenterProtocol? { get set }
}

protocol LoginPresenterProtocol: class {
    var view: LoginViewProtocol? { get set }

    func loginUser(username: String, password: String)
}
```

Comment: because the delegate will always be nil in your case.

Comment: how do i fix that @TusharSharma

Comment: you can simply pass value from class A to class B . Why need delegate here ? They are used if you want to pass back value from B to A , to achieve multiple inheritance.

Comment: ya that works. However I was looking at this link and somehow it worked for this person - https://auth0.com/blog/compare-mvvm-and-viper-architectures/ (go to where it says VIPER and you will see the code @TusharSharma

Comment: IMO this is the most confusing to utilize protocols, I mean you had to create an extra protocol for the login presenter and an extra class to deal with confirming to the protocol. But this is just MO

Comment: Ya I though so too, however VIPER architecture manages to completely separate your tasks which allows for easier unit testing and debugging @OverD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root of your problem is that you probably did not inject presenter to the view or it is not the same instance. I do not know how you deal with initialization, so I provide 2 concepts. It is better to use injection with Viper I guess.

Create init method for your presenter which takes view protocol, this applies for both approaches:

```
init(view: LoginViewProtocol) {
    self.view = view
}
```

### Registering your Dependencies

Below is example of what worked for me using Swinject(transformed to your cause but not tested).

Even though if you are not using storyboard, you can't inject both view to presenter and presenter to view in init. That is why I am using init completed here.

```
let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

container.register(LoginViewProtocol.self) { _ in
    mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(
        withIdentifier: String(describing: LoginView.self)
    ) as! LoginViewProtocol
}.initCompleted { (r, loginVC) in
    loginVC.presenter: r.resolve(LoginPresenterProtocol.self)!
}

container.register(LoginPresenterProtocol.self) { r in
    LoginPresenter(
        view: r.resolve(LoginViewProtocol.self)!
    )
}
```

Then just resolve view controller when needed to be presented.

### Without Dependency injection

Or if you do not want to deal with Dependency injection:

in `viewDidLoad`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    presenter = LoginPresenter(view: self)
}
```

This could give you an idea how to deal with that. Anyway you will have to figure out what is the best for your cause. If you are not using Dependency injection I strongly recommend it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, both ways worked great for me. I was looking on how people do it in VIPER architecture and I found a 3rd way that worked for me. Basically you are initializing everything in a wireframe file in each module. Here is a link to the file if you are intersted: https://github.com/auth0-tutorials/mvvm_viper/blob/master/VIPER%20Contacts%20Final/VIPER%20Contacts%20Final/ContactList/WireFrame/ContactListWireFrame.swift

Comment: Not sure if wireframe should handle both the creation of the view and the routing as it breaks single responsibility principle. But you can always adjust the architecture to fit your needs.